# codesmith+nettiers alternative for monodevelop

Tags: orm, mono

I really love codesmith+nettiers(+visual studio).
Is there any as good alternative for monodevelop+linuxi+postgresql?

Thanks.

Comment: They just generate code. Why can't you use them. Is PostGreSQL not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use NHibernate + 
[MindScape's NHibernate Designer for Visual Studio](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/nhdesigner)  
is  free for small models
And Nhibernate is open source, BTW: Is NetTiers Dead ?